# Meaning of icons in class browsers

Tags: pharo, squeak

Does anyone know where one can find a description of the meaning of various "icons" and / or symbols one finds next to classes and methods in various browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some classes define icons depending on their type. Collections, Streams, Morphs, Numbers, Exceptions, Announcements, Tests, etc. Have a look at the class hierarchy to understand the icon.

For methods there are two sets of icons. The first set is related to the class hierarchy:

- *Up arrow:* The method overrides a method in the superclass.
- *Down arrow:* The method is overridden by a method in a subclass.
- *Up and down arrow:* The method overrides a method in the superclass and is overridden by a method in a subclass.

The second set is used for test classes only:

- *Green dot:* The last run of the test method was a success.
- *Orange dot:* The last run of the test method was a failure.
- *Red dot:* The last run of the test method was an error.
- *Gray dot:* The test method was not recently run.

[Pharo by Example](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/25599/PBE1-2009-10-28.pdf) describes on page 114 some of these icons in more detail. Also [this website](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/hermion/icons/) contains a slightly outdated list of icons.

If you want to understand the implementation of the different icons have a look at the following two methods: The class icons are defined in `#browserIcon` and the method icons in `#browerIcon:selector:`.